# How would you configure a catch-all email system using Google Apps?

Tags: account-management

Using Google Apps for your Domain, is it possible to set up a catch-all address to act as a proxy for various other addresses on a hypothetical virtual mailbox system and, if so, how would you go about setting this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up Google Apps so that all mail delivered to a non existant address gets sent to a certain address, log into that mailbox via POP, download all mail addressed to x@your-service.com

Comment: No, I'm using Google Apps for my domain, and all mail addressed to an inexistant mailbox goes straight to me. Try it if you want: anything@charliesomerville.com ;)

Comment: It's definitely supported, see http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33962&ctx=sibling .

Answer (score 1):

You might try the free service described at http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/7f48e15a7cedafa6 ; I believe the ability for app engine to directly receive email is on Google's roadmap, but I don't know when it's scheduled to appear, or whether it will be available for free, etc, etc.